# Not getting correct output in checking for common sub-string

Tags: c

I'm trying the code for finding common sub-string and printing "YES" if it exists.

Example:

```
T=1    (NUMBER OF TEST CASES)
hello 
world
```

Output:

```
YES    ('O' is common in both)
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){

    int T,t;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    char A[100],B[100];
    int i,j,flag=0;
    t=1;
    while(t<=T){
        scanf("%[^/n]",&A);
        scanf("%[^/n]",&B);
        for(i=0;A[i]!='\0';i++){
            for(j=0;B[j]!='\0';j++){
                if(A[i]==B[j]){
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        t++;
        if(flag==1)
           printf("YES");
        else
           printf("NO");
        flag=0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0; 
   }
```

If I read the string using  `fgets(A,100,stdin)` followed by `fgets(B,100,stdin)`, compiler doesn't read second string(it is skipping the statement for some reason).

Also, when I'm using `fgets` statement inside `while` loop, it isn't reading the string at all.

Comment: `scanf("%d%*c",&T);`, `scanf("%[^/n]",&A);` --> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", A);`

Comment: when using the function: scanf() and family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using a format input/converter for stings, always limit the max number of input characters to 1 less than the number of characters in the input buffer.

Comment: the first call to scanf() is leaving the '\n' in the input buffer.  that needs to be read in/discarded before calling anymore 'string' input functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading into an array, you should not be using `&` in front of array name.  So, your `scanf`s should look like:

```
scanf("%[^/n]",A);
scanf("%[^/n]",B);
```

This is because the arrays are implemented with pointers and `A` is the address of array starting at that location.

There is a `scanf` before the loop.  The input from that is not completely removed from buffer which is causing the issue.  You can do that using `fflush(stdin);`.  Here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){

    int T, t;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    char A[100], B[100];
    int i, j, flag = 0;
    t = 1;
    while (t <= T){
        int ch;
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        fgets(A, sizeof(A), stdin);
        fgets(B, sizeof(B), stdin);
        for (i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++){
            for (j = 0; B[j] != '\0'; j++){
                if (A[i] == B[j]){
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        t++;
        if (flag == 1)
            printf("YES");
        else
            printf("NO");
        flag = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `break;` takes you out of inner loop.  You may want to `break` out of outer loop as well in case `flag == 1`.

Comment: I have changed the scanf part but now it is keep on taking the input (and finally shows wrong output). Could u run the code in your compiler and see where i  am going wrong. I have tried the online compiler. It shows wrong output as well :(  .

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: this line: 'This is because the arrays are implemented with pointers and A is the address of array starting at that location.'  is not quite true.  The implementation is exactly as expected (and array of bytes); however, in C, when referencing an array name, what is actually acquired is the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: regarding this line: 'fflush(stdin);'  'fflush()' is only for output streams and has, per the standard, undefined results when used on an input stream.  suggest: 'while( int c = getchar() && '\n' != c && EOF != c);'

Comment: Never use 'gets()'.  That function has many problems and is depreciated and removed from c11.   Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled so the compiler can catch such problems

Comment: Point well taken.  Replaced `fflush(stdin)` with `getchar` in loop.

Comment: Using `char ch;` rather than @user3629249 recommend `int ch` does not allow `ch != EOF` to function as it should.   `getchar()` can return 257 different values (`0-UCHAR_MAX` and `EOF`) and `char` cannot store them without losing distinctiveness.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is never consumed by either `scanf()` call.  The return value from `scanf("%[^/n]",&B)` is certainly not 1, as nothing is save into `B` for it stops scanning due to the `'\n'`.

```
// bad
char A[100],B[100];
scanf("%[^/n]",&A);
scanf("%[^/n]",&B);
```

Recommend to limit input to space allowed with `fgets()` and certainly not use `gets()`

```
char A[100], B[100];

// fgets() returns NULL on End-of-file or IO error
if (fgets(A, sizeof A, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
if (sscanf(A, "%d",&T) != 1) return -1;  // number not entered

if (fgets(A, sizeof A, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
A[strcspn(A, "\n")] = '\0';  // remove potential trailing \n

if (fgets(B, sizeof B, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
B[strcspn(B, "\n")] = '\0';
```